# How to manage data batches for big neural network?

Tags: python, image, deep-learning, keras

I am preparing to learn quite big neural network (fc, conv, pool, etc.) with millions of small images ( ~~100x100 px, 3 channels each) in Keras. All files will be around ~~800 GB and there is my question. How should I perpare data?

I know that Keras handles with batches but is it better to learn network with either 100 files 8 GB each or create ~~300k files (in each merged 32 or 64 images)? I think it is better to have bigger files and it is faster to read them 8 times (8 big files) than 300k times but I am not sure.

I have got less than 100 GB ram so I can not load whole data at once for sure.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator` provided by Keras instead of loading all the files into memory. It allows you to set batch size. `ImageDataGenerator` can also help you augment your data in real-time "for free" if you need. Since it takes time to train the network using a batch of images, reading files from hard drive doesn't slow down your performance. The main bottleneck is the computational power.

The interface and examples of `keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator` can be found at [ImageDataGenerator](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/)

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you can not use `keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator`, you can use your own generator.

In my case, I did segmentation and that was not supported by their `flow_from_directory` method. So I wrote my own generator, according to https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators, which yielded images indefinitely. You can use them with the `model.fit_generator` method: https://keras.io/models/model/#fit_generator.